# Better way to recognize child null and remove from database in OneToMany?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a RESTFul system and I'm having problem with two classes (Parent and Child) that have `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` relation like:

```
//Parent
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<Child> childCollection;

//Child
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PARENT", referencedColumnName = "ID_PARENT")
private Parent parent;
```

Ps.: **I'm using Hibernate 4.3**

**The problem is:**

I already have the objects in database like:

```
Parent         Child
ID | NAME      ID | PARENT | NAME
1  | Test      1  | 1      | Child1
               2  | 1      | Child2
```

I send a JSON like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "childCollection": null
}
```

I simply do:

```
session.merge(parent);
```

And I'm getting the follow error:

> A collection with cascade=”all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced
>   by the owning entity instance

Why??? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate requires complete ownership of the children collection in the parent object. If you set it to `null`, Hibernate can't track changes to that collection and thus has no idea how to apply the cascading persistence to your objects.

Your parent entity must be a managed instance. In your case, you can accomplish this by querying the entity before the call to merge. After this, if you want to clear all child elements from the parent, you must call `parent.getChildCollection().clear()` instead of setting the collection to `null`. In this way, Hibernate is really tracking the child collection. Finally do the `session.merge()` call and the error must not appear.

For more information about this:

[HibernateException - A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance](http://cristian.sulea.net/blog.php?p=2014-06-28-hibernate-exception-a-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan-was-no-longer-referenced-by-the-owning-entity-instance)